How to make an element ignored by voice over but readable by voice control
I am creating an accessibility tool in which there is a toggle button, on hovering on it pull up more content menu. To make it accessible for accessible for motor disability, I created a hidden element that do job of hovering over button, as voice control display numbers and name user would be able to understand that button do 2 things, toggling and more content menu.
This will solve purpose of motor disability using voice control but will break for voice over users(screen readers), as using navigation keys for voice over(ctrl + opt + arrow key) will move focus to hidden element and confuse users.
I created a small POC
https://codepen.io/code-freaking/pen/XWQqXJV
<html lang="en">
<body>

<div class="parent">
  <button class="button">Button</button>
  <div class="hidden element" role="button"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>


.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.button{
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.hiddenelement{
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
  
  
}


I don't well understand the usecase. How do screen reader users open the menu with more options ? Does the button do something different on click than on hover ? IF yes, it's probably a bad idea for accessibility. You are maybe trying to going around a bad design. It's better to fix the root problem than to put some scotch on it.

Is it possible that you are assuming that any one with motor disabilities would have voice control? That is definitely not the case. How can the menu be opened with keyboard or with touch screen? The demo doesn’t include behaviour (JavaScript), it’s hard for me to understand what you’re trying to achieve.

For all I know, the answer to the question in the title is that you cannot make an element available to one type of assistive technology, but not another.
